# How to pass an operator as a parameter in a clean way?

Tags: c#

I would like to pass the <= operator on doubles in a nice way

for instance

```
 var a = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
 var b = new double[] { 5.0, 1.0, 3.0 };
```

for instance, I can do this with the Math.Max function:

```
var c = a.Zip(b, Math.Max);
```

But for <= operator on double I have to write:

```
var c2 = a.Zip(b, (double x, double y)=> (x<=y));
```

which is ugly compared to the Math.Max form.

Is there a way to write this in one of the following clean ways:

```
1 - var c2 = a.Zip(b, (double operator <=));
2 - var c2 = a.Zip(b, Double.LessOrEqualTo);
```

?

Thank you,
J.

Comment: Math.Max is a function, >= is an operator. How would the compiler know what operation to execute with only an operator?

Comment: Have you tried using `Math.Min`?

Comment: @ken2k It would certainly be possible to create a syntax for it.  Operators are, more or less, just static methods with some syntactic sugar around how they're called, and the compiler is, at some level, translating it into just a call to a static method.  Creating a syntax for getting a method group from an operator is certainly possible, and if implemented, would allow the OP to do what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Servy I agree for the theoretical feasibility, but this wouldn't make sense IMO: what would be the meaning of `<=` in this context? A function that returns `x <= y` or `y <= x`?

Comment: @ken2k A function that takes two arguments and returns a boolean indication whether the first is less than or equal to the second.  This is the *exact* signature of the delegate that is expected, two operands of the same type, and a boolean result.  To determine if the second operand is less than or equal to the first the correct operator is `>=` not `<=`.

Comment: @Servy I see your point, but for me an operator shouldn't be used as a function. Of course the compiler _could_ assume you want to use the static function the operator would be a shorthand for, but that's too much assumptions for a valid syntax IMHO. Building an expression that uses the operator is much more readable (I think).

Comment: @ken2k "but for me an operator shouldn't be used as a function"`  Why's that?  An operator *is* a function; it just has a slightly different syntax for calling it.  It's still conceptually a function.  Treating it as one is certainly not conceptually wrong.

Comment: @Servy "An operator is a function" -> in the .Net world, yes, it happens to be a function, but the syntax would sound too _weird_ IMHO if an operator was used in this way. Again, I agree with your points but I wouldn't like this to be possible in C#. Of course that's personal preferences.

Comment: @ken2k The fact that creating a sensible syntax for getting the method group of an operator is hard is likely a contributing factor in why there is no such syntax.  But, as I said, it's most certainly possible, despite the fact that you claimed otherwise, and I disagree that it's not sensible, because it is.  It's likely just not worth the time/effort to implement.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it wasn't possible (or at least I didn't want to say this, maybe that wasn't clear), I just think it would be a _confusing syntax_. When I see a `<=` operator in a piece of C# code (except in the case of the operator overloading), I expect to see two operands with it. I would totally agree for the `Double.LessOrEqualTo` syntax the OP wrote, definitely not for the one with `<=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest you can get without using additional methods is:

```
var c2 = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x <= y);
```

Compiler will deduct types for `x` and `y` for you, from `a` and `b` types.

If you don't like it, you can declare helper method:

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static bool LessOrEqual(this double first, double second)
    {
        return first <= second;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var c = a.Zip(b, DoubleExtensions.LessOrEqual);
```

Comment: "Compiler will deduct types for x and y for you, from a and b types." Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @DavidHaney Give it a try and compile it! `a` is `IEnumerable<double>` and `b` is `IEnumerable<double>`, so compiler infers `x` and `y` as double.

Comment: Just a minor nit... Am I missing something or it does not actually need to be an extension method? You're calling it directly on DoubleExtensions, not on a double instance

Comment: @PaoloFalabella It doesn't. But declaring it like that gives you additional value at no cost, so I decided to do it that way.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek ahh, I did not realize that the parameter was typed by a generic argument to `Zip` which this code compiler-shortcuts. Good deal!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek got it, thanks. I was just wondering if I had missed some subtlety that made it necessary to have an extension method.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek i think your code would define `c2` as `IEnumerable<bool>` instead of `IEnumerable<double>` due to the Func returning `bool` instead of `double`

Comment: @WasifHossain That's exactly what my code does, and that's exactly why OP code does (the one with `(double x, double y) => (x<=y)`).

Comment: Nice: var c2 = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x <= y); is better than what I proposed. I still feel like having a bool myBooleanValue somewhere and then if(myBooleanValue ==true) instead of if(myBooleanValue). Nevertheless you beat me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use expression trees to create the funcs for you:

```
public static class Op
{
    public static Func<T, T, bool> Leq<T>()
    {
        var xp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var yp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var expr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(xp, yp);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(expr, xp, yp).Compile();
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
var c = a.Zip(b, Op.Leq<double>());
```

Comment: However you now have lost all compile time validation that your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your own method and pass it as argument.

```
static class DoubleClass
{
    static double LessOrEqualTo(double x, double y)
    {
        if(x <= y) return x;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
double[] c2 = a.Zip(b, DoubleClass.LessOrEqualTo).ToArray();
```

Comment: `<=` returns a `bool`, not one of the arguments.

Comment: @Servy  but the questioner requires c2 as `double[]`, not `bool[]`.

Comment: What's your basis for that assertion?  I see no evidence to support that, and considerable evidence to support the fact that his desired result is an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Answer (score -2):

`Math.Max` returns a numeric value, where the double `<=` operator returns a `bool`. How do you expect a single method to accommodate both return types (unless it is overloaded)?

Assuming it is overloaded, you could create a `Func<double, double, bool>` which would take 2 `double`s as inputs and return a `bool`:

```
Func<double, double, bool> myDoubleFunc = (x, y) => { return x <= y };
```

Then call it:

```
var c2 = a.Zip(b, myDoubleFunc(1.0, 2.0));
```

Comment: [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) will indeed accept either.

Comment: To answer your literal question, the answer is "generics".  That's how `Zip` is able to accept a delegate without knowing it's return type.  The return type is a generic argument to `Zip`.